# Reusable app, define block only if not defined

Tags: django, django-templates

My app uses django's messaging middleware.

In the base template for this app I have:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block messages %}
<ul class="messagelist">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}_message"{% endif %}>{{ message|capfirst }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock messages %}
```

The problem is that this would override the 'messages' block in the site-scoped `base.html`.

So if I have styles defined in the site base as in this example:

```
{% block messages %}
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messagelist ui-state-highlight">
    {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}_message"{% endif %}>{{ message|capfirst }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock messages %}
```

My 'reusable' template would remove `ui-state-highlight`...

**Any way I can define the block messages in my app's base only if it is not defined?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I follow what you're trying to do - write an app that will provide content for the block if needed, but use its parent template's block if available - I think this should do it:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block messages %}
    {% if block.super %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% else %}
        <ul class="messagelist">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}_message"{% endif %}>{{ message|capfirst }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

That's untested, though - it's possible that `block.super` works oddly.  And it won't distinguish between your parent template not defining a `messages` block at all and defining an empty block.